# cxf.version 3.2.1 giving org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolErrorListener error

Tags: maven, java-8, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am trying to build a mavnen project with cxf-codegen-plugin. I am using cxf version 3.2.1, maven compiler plugin 3.7.0 ,java version 8 and I am building this in Intellij idea on ubuntu platform. Below is my **pom.xml** plugin details -

```
 <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${encoding.type}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

**and my dependency details -**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**Below is the stack trace of the error I am getting -**

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ interfaces ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ interfaces ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/tools/common/ToolErrorListener
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolErrorListener
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.275 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-06T17:14:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project interfaces: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java: org/apache/cxf/tools/common/ToolErrorListener
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin/3.2.1/cxf-codegen-plugin-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolErrorListener
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

**After adding dependencies in the plugin as:**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ interfaces ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:675)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:613)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:569)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:555)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.BuildContext
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 58 more
```

**After adding :**

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
            </dependency>
```

**I am getting this error :**

```
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.1:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ dmappservice-client-java ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/Bus
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:688)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:380)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:613)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:569)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:555)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:884)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.Bus
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 58 more
```

Can someone explain me why is it happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding below dependencies

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.5</version>
                </dependency>
                <!--new jars added below-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-tools-wsdlto-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                    <version>4.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                    <artifactId>velocity-engine-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-tools-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The problem was that these dependencies should be injected into project from parent project, which was not happening. When I added these dependencies manually to child project, my error has been resolved. Seems to be some maven compiler issue.

Comment: Many thanks you saved my day! I added dependencies jaxb-impl and jaxb-xjc for cxf-codegen-plugin and it works for me

Comment: Congrats! :D Glad that it helped you :)